# binary_search_by returns a strange index when using a custom struct

Tags: rust

My function `get_index` should return the index of asserted element

```
pub const INVALID_INDEX: usize = <usize>::max_value();
```

```
pub fn get_index(&mut self, element: T) -> usize
where
    T: std::cmp::Ord,
{
    if self.data.is_empty() {
        return 0;
    }

    match self.data.binary_search_by(|probe| probe.cmp(&element)) {
        Ok(pos) => return pos,
        Err(pos) => return INVALID_INDEX,
    }
}
```

To provide a test, I create a value and some mock data:

```
let mut list: List<FooModel> = List::new();

let my_foo_1 = FooModel {name: "John".to_string(), id_num: 10};
let my_foo_2 = FooModel {name: "Bill".to_string(), id_num: 20};

list.add(my_foo_1.clone());
list.add(my_foo_2.clone());
list.add(my_foo_3.clone());   
list.add(my_foo_4.clone()); 
list.add(my_foo_5.clone());
```

the problem occurs when I try to get a index for the first element

```
println!("Element is at index {:?}",list.get_index(my_foo_1.clone()));
```

I get the `INVALID_INDEX` value returned for `my_foo_1`; all other expressions return the correct index value.

If I create a list with some generic types:

```
let mut list_2: List<u32> = List::new();
list_2.add(1);
list_2.add(2);
list_2.add(3);
list_2.add(4);
```

I get the correct result for the call:

```
println!("Element is at index {:?}", list_2.get_index(1));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Idiomatically, you should not use sentinel values like `INVALID_INDEX` in Rust. It's much better to make use of a type like `Option`. Using explicit `return` keywords at the end of the method is also non-idiomatic.

Comment: you didn't provide enough information to answer you, for exemple, what does `add()` ? What does `new()` ? etc etc what is `List` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem:

```
fn main() {
    let data = vec!["John", "Bill"];

    let v = data.binary_search_by(|probe| probe.cmp(&"John")).ok();

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

The first sentence of the [documentation for `binary_search_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by) states (emphasis mine):

> Binary searches this **sorted** slice with a comparator function.

Your data is (most likely, because you have neglected to show the relevant code) not sorted.

Comment: Hi @Shepmaster, thanks for advice.
I made some changes (according to your suggestion) but Im still got the same result.

Can you please check what Im do wrong, the whole project is here:
[link text] (https://github.com/sinocpp/Rust_Learning_Repository/tree/master/Base%20Rust/02%20Data%20structures%20and%20alghoritams/lists/src)

Comment: @sino what changes did you make? Did you **sort** the data? I see no sorting in your code. Please **[edit]** your question to include a [MCVE]. Reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.